# Python: a new column name in a function with assign()

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

In the following code, I created a function to return a DataFrame with a new column `new_col` with one-period shifted values of `ori_col`. But, a new column of the output has the name `new_col` rather than `B`. What am I missing here?

```
import pandas as pd

def add_col_diff(dframe, ori_col, new_col):
    shift_1 = dframe[ori_col].shift(1)
    return dframe.assign(new_col=shift_1)

data = {'A': [10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df = add_col_diff(df, 'A', 'B')
df
```

This gives

```
     A  new_col
0   10  NaN
1   11  10.0
2   12  11.0
```

Comment: I'm actually completely confused by this. `return dframe.assign('B'=shift_1)` is not valid, so it presumably takes the argument name rather than its value?

Comment: Yes, `return dframe.assign(B=shift_1)` will work, but I don't see how you reasonably convey that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`assign` will set the keyword arguments as the column names. Simply having `assign(new_col=shift_l)` will make a column with the name `new_col`. *Keyword arguments are not evaluated as variables.*

If you want to use variables to define your column names, you can unpack from a **dictionary**. Try:

```
dframe.assign(**{new_col: shift_1})
```

---

An alternative is to use:

```
dframe[new_col] = shift_1
```

Comment: Do you know _why_ it works like this? The OP's attempt seems pretty reasonable to me

Comment: Keyword arguments do not resolve variables. The answer is using the correct syntax of casting a dictionary to keywords ( IE: the dictionary will resolve the variables )

Comment: @John so this is a necessary evil of allowing multiple assignments in one call?

Comment: @roganjosh not necessarily, it's just the idiom for how keyword arguments are declared. As demonstrated above, you can assign a dictionary "key" + "Value" using a variable/single call.

Comment: If this weren't the case, function keywords would need quotes around them... too much energy for those extra key presses.